# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, remote-sensing, anaconda, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to follow this tutorial: [land cover fastai](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/eo-learn/blob/master/examples/land-cover-fastai/deep_lulc_walkthrough.ipynb)
And while executing the workflow, I got this error:

[image]

This is the code where the error occurs:

```
def png_gen(patch, inference=False):
    """Save RGB, spectral info and labeled images for the coming deep learning

    Args:
        patch: Saved eopatches for deep learning LULC training and prediction 
    Return:
        None: images in the PNG.
    """

    patch_data = EOPatch.load(patch)
    patch_dir, patch_id = patch.split("/")
    if inference == True:
        inds_path = "inds_inference"

        if not op.isdir(inds_path):
            makedirs(inds_path)
        for i in range(len(bands)):
            #get NDVI, NDWI and NDBI from the bands
            inds = color_scale(bands[i][..., [-3, -2, -1]]).astype("uint8")
            Image.fromarray(inds).save(op.join(inds_path, patch+'_'+str(i)+'.png'))

    else:
        lulc = patch_data.mask_timeless['LULC']
        lulc_path = "lulc_all"
        rgb_path = "rgb_all"
        inds_path = "inds_all"
        if not op.isdir(lulc_path):
            makedirs(lulc_path)
        if not op.isdir(rgb_path):
            makedirs(rgb_path)
        if not op.isdir(inds_path):
            makedirs(inds_path)
        for i in range(len(bands)):
            # Switch R, G, B band index from bands
            rgb = color_scale(bands[i][..., [2, 1, 0]]).astype("uint8")
            inds = color_scale(bands[i][..., [-3, -2, -1]]).astype("uint8")
            Image.fromarray(rgb).save(op.join(rgb_path, "{}_{}.png".format(patch_id, str(i))))
            Image.fromarray(inds).save(op.join(inds_path, "{}_{}.png".format(patch_id, str(i))))
            Image.fromarray(lulc).save(op.join(lulc_path, "{}_{}.png".format(patch_id, str(i))))
```

And this is the execution code:

```
#download eopatch for the desired AOI and covert the numpy array into RGB, spectral info (NDVI, NDWI, NDBI) 
# and training lulc label into PNG and saved them under "rgb_all", "inds_all" and "lulc_all"
pbar = tqdm(total=len(patchIDs))
for idx, bbox in enumerate(tile_list[patchIDs]):
    # define additional parameters of the workflow
    extra_param = {
        add_data: {'bbox': bbox, 'time_interval': time_interval},
        save_s2: {'eopatch_folder': 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)}
    }

    workflow.execute(extra_param)
    print("eopatch {} has been processed!".format(idx))
    # png_gen('eopatch_{}'.format(idx))
    png_gen(op.join(path_out_sampled, 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)), inference=False)
    print("Saving RGB, LULC and Inds PNG to eopatch_{} for the coming ML pipeline".format(idx))
    # del 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)
    shutil.rmtree(op.join(path_out_sampled, 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)), ignore_errors=True)
    print("eopatch_{} deleted!".format(idx))
    pbar.update(1)
```

Instead of  '/' I tried  '_' in this line  `patch_dir, patch_id = patch.split("/")` because the downloaded patches have this format "eopatch_idx", but I got the same error.

This where the downloaded data are stored:

```
path_out_sampled = './eopatches_sampled_Slovenia/'
if not op.isdir(path_out_sampled):
    makedirs(path_out_sampled)
save_s2 = SaveToDisk(path_out_sampled, overwrite_permission=OverwritePermission.OVERWRITE_PATCH)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the `split()` functions returns more value than the variables used on the left side of the `=` operator.
I quickly tried the following code snippet:

```
s = "./eopatches_sampled_Slovenia/"
s.split("/")
['.', 'eopatches_sampled_Slovenia', '']
a,b = s.split("/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
a,b = s.split("_")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

In both cases the `split()` returns 3 element and, if only 2 variables are used (`a, b` in my example), the `ValueError` is raised by Python.
Depending on what you need to achieve, the solution is either to use a third variable and then discard it (e.g., `_var_to_discard`) or to use another function like shown hereafter:

```
s.strip("./")
'eopatches_sampled_Slovenia'
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I did try the Extended Iterable Unpacking method by adding " *others" on the left side of the equation, but since I got other errors subsequently to that one. I didn't post it as a solution until I make sure that these errors are not related to adding the third element.

Comment: I concur that the error occurs at `patch_dir, patch_id = patch.split("/")`, because it is expecting 2 values from the split. You could try using os.path.basename and similar functions to extract the directory and filename.